# DXA 1.4.1 compilation and cd_broker:jar:8.1.1-1007 mising

Tags: dxa, 2013-sp1, dxa-java

We are using Hotfix 1.4.1 version for upgrade but compilation is giving an error that `cd_broker:jar:8.1.1-1007` is missing from maven.

```
D:\SDL-DXA-java\sh_dxa_hotfix_1_4_1\dxa-web-application-java\dxa-example-webapp>mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 1 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 1 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DXA - Example Webapp 1.4.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.sdl.web:content-client-api:jar:8.1.1-1007 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.sdl.web:discovery-client-lightweight:jar:8.1.1-1008 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.tridion:cd_broker:jar:8.1.1-1007 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ dxa-example-webapp ---

[INFO] Deleting D:\SDL-DXA-java\sh_dxa_hotfix_1_4_1\dxa-web-application-java\dxa-example-webapp\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ dxa-example-webapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ dxa-example-webapp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 25 source files to D:\SDL-DXA-java\sh_dxa_hotfix_1_4_1\dxa-web-application-java\dxa-example-webapp\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/SDL-DXA-java/sh_dxa_hotfix_1_4_1/dxa-web-application-java/dxa-example-webapp/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/modules/generic/utilclasses/TaxonomyComparator.java:[3,30] package com.tridion.taxonomies does not exist
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.353 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-26T09:19:50+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/46M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project dxa-example-webapp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /D:/SDL-DXA-java/sh_dxa_hotfix_1_4_1/dxa-web-application-java/dxa-example-webapp/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/modules/generic/utilclasses/TaxonomyComparator.java:[3,30] package com.tridion.taxonomies does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

D:\SDL-DXA-java\sh_dxa_hotfix_1_4_1\dxa-web-application-java\dxa-example-webapp>
```

Comment: The project is referencing cd_broker:jar:8.1.1-1007 which we don't have. We downloaded SDL Web 8.1.1 which contains cd_broker:jar:8.1.1-1008. Where can we get cd_broker:jar:8.1.1-1007 or how can we change the reference to cd_broker so that the project compiles with cd_broker:jar:8.1.1-1008? Note that we are trying to build this project for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and not Web 8.

Answer (score 1):

`cd_broker:8.1.1` is a part of backend, and is not intended to be used inside your web application. [SDL CIL 8.1.1](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.sdl.web%7Ccil%7C8.1.1-1021%7Cpom) is to be used for this. `content-compatible` artifact is there for backward-compatibility when migrating from 2013SP1; so you can find classes you used previously there.

Then, artifacts `8.*.*` are not part of 2013SP1 but are a part of Web 8 release.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment that we are trying to build this web-app for a 2013SP1 setup. We are not on Web8 yet. So how can we get this working for 2013SP1. Please pardon my ignorance.